# Why ravens play with garbage?

Tags: ornithology, behaviour

Why ravens play with small plastic details and other garbage?

Could you explain how this behavior was formed by evolution for birds-scavengers?

Answer (score 6):

Ravens and other corvids are [among the most intelligent birds](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2018/03/year-of-the-bird-brains-intelligence-smarts/). Of note, crows and ravens are known for their ability to solve problems that require tool use, memory, and delayed rewards (patience).

Many animals play, and [ravens](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/do-birds-play/) and [crows](https://corvidresearch.blog/2015/03/16/crow-curiosities-do-crows-play-and-why/) are no exception. ([A study entirely on raven nestling play](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9ef5/37557b1efd2cc60fc4011b1060d6cec3983e.pdf).) The evolutionary purpose of play activity is thought to improve coordination/dexterity, provide exercise, strengthen muscles (such as wing-flapping by young birds that have yet to fledge), and develop social skills.

As to what type of objects ravens find most interesting to play with, I'm unsure of a definitive answer. Some birds, particularly the [satin bowerbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satin_bowerbird), even *collect* colorful objects. My hypothesis is that the choice of object is likely due to simple availability (discarded) and conspicuous nature (color). In other words, ravens more easily find such objects *because* they are colorful, which in turn are frequently human-manufactured.

Comment: What is specific  in "forest scavengers life style" that pushed them to become most intelligent birds?

Comment: Quite a while ago I read "[Mind of the Raven](https://www.amazon.com/Mind-Raven-Investigations-Adventures-Wolf-Birds/dp/0061136050)" by Bernd Heinrich, an expert in ravens. If I recall correctly, he suggests that ravens will essentially investigate any object they haven't seen before. Then after learning about these objects, they don't find them as interesting anymore.

Comment: @Eff An excellent book! Indeed chapter 24 is dedicated to play. I recall the same; I think it may also have been implied that investigating objects could contribute to finding new food sources.

Comment: @JYelton *"I think it may also have been implied that investigating objects could contribute to finding new food sources."* That's exactly what I remember being suggested.